# Tengo dos ventanas modales. Una funciona a la perfección y la otra no se ejecuta. PHP, AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, modal, consola

soy novato en programacion web y estoy haciendo cursos poco a poco para ir tomando experiencia. Sin embargo en mi trabajo me han dado la libertad de trabajar con sus paginas web y tengo un problema con dos ventana modal. En las dos quiero validar una fecha de disponibilidad para una sala de capacitacion que se renta. La validacion me funciona pero solo lo hace en una ventana modal ya que en la segunda ventana no logra ejecutarse.

Perdonen por si es una novatada. Hasta ahora todo lo he solucionado investigando en este tipo de foros pero con este problema no doy con su solucion.

Agradeceria su comprension. Estoy empezando por lo que espero sean respetuosos. Gracias

[image: modal1]

[image: modal2]

CODIGO DE VENTANAS MODAL:

```js
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
    });
  } );
   
 $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    });
  } );
</script>
```

```html
<!-- js -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="n_js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="n_js/bootstrap-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="1js/main2.js"></script>
    
    <!--datePicker-->
  <link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


 


  <!--//datePicker-->

    
<!-- MODAL PAQUETE BASICO -->
    
<?php

 $cursos=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM publicacion WHERE pub_date_end>='$hoy'OR pub_date_start<='$inicio'");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($cursos))
 {
     
     echo '
  <div class="modal fade" id="1reg_'.$row['id_public'].'" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
    
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <center><h4 class="modal-title">'.$row['pub_title'].'</h4></center>
                    </div>
                    
            <div class="modal-body">
            
             <center>
             <h3>Informaci&oacute;n de Renta de Espacio</h3>
             </center>
             <br>
             
       <div class="col-md-6">    
    <center>         
     <h3>Datos de Contacto</h3>
     </center>
     <br>
     <br>
     <center>
  <form action="process/check_renta.php" method="post">   
  <h4>Empresa</h4><input type="text" name="empresa" required onkeypress="return pulsar(event)"><br><br>
  <h4>Contacto</h4><input type="text" name="contacto" required onkeypress="return pulsar(event)"><br><br>
  <h4>Tel&eacute;fono</h4><input type="text" name="telefono" required onkeypress="return pulsar(event)"><br><br>
  <h4>Correo Electr&oacute;nico</h4><input type="email" name="email_cli" required onkeypress="return pulsar(event)"><br><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="modalidad" value="PAQUETE BASICO">
  <input type="hidden" name="parent_pub" value="'.$row['id_public'].'"> 

  </center>
  
  </center>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <center>         
     <h3>Fecha de Evento</h3>
  </center>
  <br>
  <br>
  <center>
   <h4>Fecha Inicio</h4><input type="text" name="reg_date_start" id="datepicker" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"><br><br>
   <h4>Fecha Finalizaci&oacute;n</h4><input type="text" name="reg_date_end" id="datepicker1" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
   <div id="datos"></div>
        </div>
        </center>
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <center>
            <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btn btn-success"><br>
        </center>
        </form>
        </div><br>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        
        
        
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  ';
     
 }
?>

<!-- MODAL PAQUETE BASICO -->

<!-- MODAL PAQUETE PLUS -->    
    
<?php

 $cursos=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM publicacion WHERE pub_date_end>='$hoy'OR pub_date_start<='$inicio'");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($cursos))
 {
     
     echo '
  <div class="modal fade" id="2reg_'.$row['id_public'].'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
    
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <center><h4 class="modal-title">'.$row['pub_title'].'</h4></center>
                    </div>
                    
            <div class="modal-body">
            
             <center>
             <h3>Informaci&oacute;n de Renta de Espacio</h3>
             </center>
             <br>
             
       <div class="col-md-6">    
    <center>         
     <h3>Datos de Contacto</h3>
     </center>
     <br>
     <br>
     <center>
  <form action="process/check_renta.php" method="post">   
  <h4>Empresa</h4><input type="text" name="empresa" required onkeypress="return pulsar(event)"><br><br>
  <h4>Contacto</h4><input type="text" name="contacto" required onkeypress="return pulsar(event)"><br><br>
  <h4>Tel&eacute;fono</h4><input type="text" name="telefono" required onkeypress="return pulsar(event)"><br><br>
  <h4>Correo Electr&oacute;nico</h4><input type="email" name="email_cli" required onkeypress="return pulsar(event)"><br><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="modalidad" value="PAQUETE PLUS">
  <input type="hidden" name="parent_pub" value="'.$row['id_public'].'"> 

  </center>
  
  </center>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <center>         
     <h3>Fecha de Evento</h3>
  </center>
  <br>
  <br>
  <center>
   <h4>Fecha Inicio</h4><input type="text" name="reg_date_start" id="datepicker" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"><br><br>
   <h4>Fecha Finalizaci&oacute;n</h4><input type="text" name="reg_date_end" id="datepicker1" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
   <div id="datos"></div>
        </div>
        </center>
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <center>
            <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btn btn-success"><br>
        </center>
        </form>
        </div><br>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        
        
        
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  ';
     
 }
?>

<!-- MODAL PAQUETE PLUS -->
```

CODIGO AJAX:

```js
$(buscar_datos());

function buscar_datos(consulta){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'buscar2.php' ,
  type: 'POST' ,
  dataType: 'html',
  data: {consulta: consulta},
 })
 .done(function(respuesta){
  $("#datos").html(respuesta);
 })
 .fail(function(){
  console.log("error");
 });
}


$(document).on('change','#datepicker', function(){
 var valor = $(this).val();
 if (valor != "") {
  buscar_datos(valor);
 }else{
  buscar_datos();
 }
});

$(document).on('change','#datepicker2', function(){
 var valor = $(this).val();
 if (valor != "") {
  buscar_datos(valor);
 }else{
  buscar_datos();
 }
});
```

CODIGO BUSCAR DISPONIBILIDAD PHP:

```html
<?php

$hoy=date('Y-m-d');

 $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "inaciepm_root";
   $password = "Cisc0UV07";
   $dbname = "inaciepm_icms";

 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Conexion fallida: ".$conn->connect_error);
      }

    $salida = "";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM reg_pub WHERE reg_date_start > '$hoy' ORDER By reg_date_start";

    if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
     $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
     
     $query = "SELECT * FROM reg_pub WHERE '$q' BETWEEN reg_date_start AND reg_date_end";
     
     /*$query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM reg_pub WHERE ((reg_date_start > '$hoy' AND reg_date_start >= '$q') OR reg_date_end >= '$q') ";*/
    }
    

    $resultado = $conn->query($query);

    if ($resultado->num_rows>0) {
     $salida.="<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
  Fecha No Disponible!
</div>";


    }else{
     $salida.="<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>
                    Fecha Disponible!
                </div>";
    }


    echo $salida;
    
   


?>
```

ERROR EN LA CONSOLA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error en la consola dice: `Se encontraron 2 elementos con id no unica "#datepicker"`  No puedes usar el mismo id para los dos modales.

Comment: Si gracias. En ocasiones lo he corregido y he utilizado distintos ID para los input de fecha y la incidencia persiste. Ahora mismo los tengo con dos id distintos y sin el error en la consola y sigue sin mostrarse el segundo modal